# How to show SVN revision in Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin instead of job number?

Tags: jenkins, build-pipeline-plugin

I am using the Jenkins Build Pipeline plugin.
Do you know how to show the SVN revision in Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin instead of job number?

I have seen in screenshot of old versions of this plugin that it showed SVN revision sometimes.
Is it a change into the plugin, or some parameter to add?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Build Name Setter Plugin" to set the name of the build, but this is not respected by the Build Pipeline plugin. At present it is hard coded to use the build revision number, so you can not at present configure it.

As reference, you can see this in the source code on

http://code.google.com/p/build-pipeline-plugin/source/browse/src/main/resources/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/BuildPipelineView/bpp.jelly

on line 319

```
<div>
  Pipeline
  <j:if test="${from.isShowPipelineParameters()}">
  ${buildGrid.get(x).get(0).getRevision()}
  </j:if>
</div>
```

I would also like to see the plugin respect the display name of the build as set by the Build Name Setter plugin. There's an open issue for this feature on the Build Pipeline plugin Google code page. http://code.google.com/p/build-pipeline-plugin/issues/detail?id=94

EDIT:
I dug a bit deeper into the source code and it seems that some changes have been made after the 1.3 release. The relevant commit is http://code.google.com/p/build-pipeline-plugin/source/detail?r=d8f1b6ab3e4e78383a89994cc569e11542b1e532. Hopefully this functionality will be rolled out in the next release.